# Почему первый компьютер подключается ко второму, а второй к первому нет? - C#

Tags: c#, сокет, клиент-сервер, ip, lan

Пишу клиент-серверное приложение (сокеты). В одном проекте и сервер, и клиент.

Вот примерная суть работы.
Допустим, есть два компьютера А и Б. Компьютер А пытается подключиться к Б, и его ловит сервер Б (сервер А остается в покое), причем компьютер Б устанавливает соединение со свои сервером прямо при запуске программы. Так происходит соединение.

Проблема заключается в следующем: компьютер А свободно подключается к Б, но когда я пытаюсь подключиться из Б к А, соединение не устанавливается.

Код на А и на Б полностью идентичен! IP-адреса я ввожу по ходу программы, ввожу правильно. Подключаюсь сразу после полного запуска программы на обоих компьютерах. А и Б находятся в локальной сети.

Замечу, что при подключении А к Б, метод AcceptCallback, который принимает подключения, на сервере Б вызывается.
При подключении Б к А, на сервере А ни шороху. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Файерволл?(5 символов нужно)

Comment: ОС (с версией)? Наличие стороннего антивирусного ПО (может содержать файервол)? Настройки встроенного в ось файервола (если есть, см. первый вопрос)? Какое-то другое ПО, которое может использовать тот же порт? C# тут точно ни причем, если, раз вы сами утверждаете, что код идентичен и в одну сторону все работает хорошо.

Comment: Да, это был файерволл! Не могу понять, почему я сразу об этом не подумал. Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте понять принцип работы файерволла: он блокирует входящие соединения, но спокойно пропускает исходящие (типа, всё доверено). (В скобках замечу, что rdorn совершенно прав: при дефолтных настройках, большинством файерволлом, а при желании можно разумеется накрутить и драконовских правил)

Поэтому то, что вы спокойно подключаетесь из А к Б означает лишь, что порт вашего решения не заблокирован на Б.

А когда вы меняете местами клиент и сервер -- то нужно ещё и на А проверить порт, потому что теперь для А соедения станут входящими/недоверенными.

Так что проверяйте файерволлы/антивирусы и прочие решения, которые могут блокировать порты.

Comment: стоит уточнить, что исходящие не блокируются *большинством* файерволов только по-умолчанию (для win server с поднятым AD DC, например, это не верно), в ручном режиме можно блокировать все что угодно, даже на встроенном в Windows файерволе.

Comment: @rdorn Это правда. Очень увлекательное и поучительное занятие -- сидеть и подтверждать каждое исходящее соединение, можно много нового узнать о своей системе. И так же увлекательно смотреть монитор приложений. Правда, всё это быстро надоедает.